# Is this language Context-Free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

Is the language

$$L = \{a,b\}^* \setminus \{(a^nb^n)^n\mid n \geq1 \}$$

context-free? I believe that the answer is that it is not a CFL, but I can't prove it by Ogden's lemma or Pumping lemma.

Comment: Crossposted on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/166315/3330); please don't do that! Did you check out the [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/98) I pointed you to? Please include your attempts and why they fail.

Comment: [Parikh's theorem](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/279/98) works for $\{(a^nb^n)^n \mid n \geq 1\}$ but not for $L$; unfortunately, $\Psi_{\{a,b\}}[L] = \mathbb{N}^2$. Even the [Interchange lemma](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/437/98) seems to be fulfilled. Wow, nasty one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

> Yes

Solution:

> $$\{(a^n b^n)^n \mid n \geq 1 \} = \{a^{n_1} b^{n_2} \dots a^{n_{2k-1}} b^{n_{2k}}\}: k \geq 1 \land n_1 = k \land \forall i. n_i = n_{i+1} \}$$
>
>  and therefore the complement is
>
>  $$\{a,b\}^{\ast} \setminus \{(a^n b^n)^n \mid n \geq 1 \} = \{a^{n_1} b^{n_2} \dots a^{n_{2k-1}} b^{n_{2k}}: n_1 \neq k \lor \exists i. n_i \neq n_{i+1}\}$$
>
>  which is context-free as you can easily write a nondeterministic PDA.

Comment: Ooohhh! \*facepalm\* Maybe you want to add the central design trick; it might not be obvious for the novice.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought that the complement of a CFL wasn't CFL in general. Thank you

Comment: $\{(a^n b^n)^n\}$ is not context-free, but its complement is.

Comment: @AndrésFelipeTéllezCrespo: The complement of a CFL is not *always* CFL (so no closure property) but nobody says that there is no CFL whose complement is CFL. In particular, all the complements of all regular languages are context-free (because they are even regular).

Comment: Languages similar to $L$ -- a finite disjunction of suitable conditions -- can be solved by using nondeterminism: *guess* the violated condition and verify that it is violated (ignore the rest).