# Proving the language of words with equal numbers of symbols non-context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)

I'm having a hard time figuring this out, any help is appreciated.

Let EQUAL be the language of all words over $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ that have the same number of $a$’s, $b$’s and $c$’s

$\qquad \text{EQUAL} = \{ w \in \Sigma^* \mid |w|_a = |w|_b = |w|_c \}$

The order of the letters doesn't matter. How can you prove that EQUAL is non-context-free?

Comment: Check the various methods given at [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/157)

Comment: It's actually an example in [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/437/98). Closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that the intersection of a context-free language with a regular language is context-free. If EQUAL were context-free, so would be its intersection with $a^*b^*c^*$, which is the well-known non-context-free $\{a^nb^nc^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.