# Why is the following language not context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, automata, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

$L = \{a^n b^m | m \not= n^2 \}$ 
I guess I need to use Pumping Lemma for CFL in order to prove this. But I'm stuck.

Assuming that $ a^n b^m = uvxyz$, we know that $v$ or $y$ can not have both $a$ and $b$ symbols in them. Otherwise pumping would generate strings not of the form $a^i b^j$.

Hence both $v$ and $y$ must consist only of one kind of symbol each.
Beyond this I wonder what string in $L$ has to be chosen in order to pump and obtain something of the form $a^n b^{n^2}$.

***Alternative idea :*** Assuming that $L$ is context-free, then I must have a PDA accepting it by final state. Can I say that this PDA can be adjusted* to accept $L'$ i.e., all $a^n b^{n^2}$ ? However I know that $L'$ is not a CFL. Hence, contradiction ?

*Adjusted = Make the non-final state on reading $a^n b^{n^2}$ as final and the rest as all non-final.

Comment: Have a look at our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) for more techniques.

Comment: Is this not a context free language? Since when $m=n$ this language is Context Free

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is not very clear. What are $n$ and $m$? You have to *fix* a word in order to use the Pumping lemma; please see [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) for how it's done.

Your second approach is fundamentally flawed as CFL is *not* closed against complement, i.e. your PDA construction does not work. Also, note that $L^c$ does not only contain words of the form $a^nb^{n^2}$, but also all that do not match $a^*b^*$.

Towards showing that $L$ is not context-free, note that $\mathrm{CFL} \cap \mathcal{L}(a^* b^*)$ is closed against complement (see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11110/are-context-free-languages-in-ab-closed-under-complement)). Therefore, if $L$ was context-free so would be

$\qquad L' = \{a^n b^m \mid m = n^2\}$.

It is easy to show that $L'$ is not context-free by using the Pumping lemma.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing it out. I edited the question. I meant, we could adjust the PDA a little bit to make it accept a language that is not context-free.
As for the first approach, my problem is with that exactly. What should be $m$ and $n$? All I have done is stating some generic statements that holds good for any $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @Enigman Please work through the [examples in the reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free), that should answer your question. Basically, you are approaching the Pumping lemma in a completely wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Examining [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/279/157) mentioned by Raphael,

I don't believe the pumping lemma could help you with this language. It seems you can always choose the part to pump so that you will "miss" the condition that $m=n^2$.

I also believe the same difficulty will be there if you try to use Ogden's Lemma, which generalize the pumping lemma to deal with such problematic questions, (marking $N$ places will reduce to pumping the marked substring.)

However, the method using Parikh's Theorem, should work and is not very difficult for this case, since $\Psi(L) = \{ (n,m) \mid m\ne n^2\}$. You are left to show that it is not a finite union of "linear" sets. Not too easy, but should be doable.