# Prove that regular languages and context-free languages aren't closed under $Perm(L)$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Let the operation $$Perm(L) = \{ w | \exists u \in L \text{ such that } u \text{ is a permutation of } w \}$$

> Prove that both regular languages and CFLs aren't closed under $Perm(L)$.

I've tried to use several well-known languages (like $\{0^n1^n\}$) and applying $Perm(L)$ and afterward manipulate them or using the pumping lemma in order to get a contradiction, but nothing worked out.

Comment: You *are* aware that you should do your homework on your own?

Comment: See also: [Are permutations of context-free languages context-free?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/are-permutations-of-context-free-languages-context-free).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

1. For regular languages, consider $Perm((01)^*) \cap 0^* 1^*$.
2. For context-free languages, consider $Perm(0^n 1^n 2^m 3^m) \cap 0^* 2^* 1^* 3^*$.

Comment: And also $Perm((012)^*) \cap 0^*1^*2^*$, which jumps from regular ouside context-free.