# For a regular language L, the language of all words such that no prefix of them are in L is also regular

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Prove that for every regular language $L$, the following language is regular:

$L_{pf}=$ $\{x \in L | $ no proper prefix of $x$ is in $L\}$

How should I prove this?

I understood that $L_{pf}$ is just subset of $L$ and the words inside it are special such that no word is the prefix of other one, is this right ? it's not hard if I have the words in $L$ to prove this, but how to generalise it ?

Comment: Hint: Think of a DFA $\mathcal{A}$ for $L$, for $L_{pf}$ you only want to accept the runs on $\mathcal{A}$ that end in an accepting state but never pass through an accepting state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are regular and context free languages closed against making them prefix-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13388/are-regular-and-context-free-languages-closed-against-making-them-prefix-free). In particular the answer by Raphael, where it is argued that $L_{pf} = L \setminus (L\cdot \Sigma^+)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L' = \{xx'\,|\,x\in L\,\&\,|x'|>0\}$. Your language $L_{pf} = L\setminus L'$, so constructing DFA for $L'$ solves your task, since you can use the closure properties.

Consider a DFA $A$ recognizing $L$. Let $F$ be the set of the final states of $A$. Add a new final state $q_T$ to $A$ and for every final $q_i\in F$ and every terminal $s$ add the transitions $(q_i, s, q_T)$ to your automaton. Finally, make all the states in $F$ non-final. You get an NFA recognising words with the proper prefixes in $L$, and in order to use the closure properties you need to apply a determinisation algorithm. Afterwards, construct the complement and the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Take a DFA for $L$. Make every exiting transition from a final state go to a non-final sink state instead. (Proof details left to you)

Comment: by the "non-final sink state" do you mean dead state?

Comment: Yes, that's it.