# Does this language have a context-free grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Here is a question that I encountered in one of my exams:

> Find one context-free grammar that recognizes the language:
>   $\qquad L = \{a^n(b^mc^m)^pd^n \mid m, n, p \geq 0\} $

Can you find such a grammar? I even doubt its existence, but I have not been able to prove that.

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, have you tried [disproving](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) the claim?

Comment: @Raphael: I tried using the "pumping" lemma. Do you want to see the proof? (I haven't verify that it's correct though!)

Comment: Now it's too late as you already have answers. Make sure you make your attempts prior to posting next time you have a question! (Beware falling into the "check-my-answer" trap, though; see [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/questions-about-correctness-of-a-solution).)

Answer (score 3):

No, this language is not context-free. This is because the language requires to iterate $b^mc^m$ with the same number $m$ each time. Even if we restrict to $n=0$ and $p=2$ then the resulting language $\{b^mc^mb^mc^m \mid m\ge 0\}$ is easily recognized as non-context-free. Formally this restriction is obtained by intersecting with a regular language, a known closure property of context-free languages. To prove a language formally non-context-free one might use the pumping lemma discussed [elsewhere in this forum](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free).

Perhaps that is a mistake in its specification. If for each iteration the number $m$ can be different, the resulting language is context-free. That language would be $L_1 = \{ a^n w d^n \mid n\ge 0, w\in \{\; b^mc^m \mid m\ge 0\}^*  \;\}$. As an example, $bbbcccbc$ is an element of $L_1$, but not of $L$.

*How* to find a grammar (for $L_1$)? Observe the nesting structure. Context-free grammars are good in nesting, and iteration. For instance the part $\{\; b^mc^m \mid m\ge 0\}^*$ is generated by $T\to AT, T\to A, A\to bAc, A\to\lambda$, starting with $T$. Now add a matching number of $a$'s and $d$'s on both sides by nesting: $S \to aSd, S\to T$.

Comment: Why would requiring the same numbers of $b$s and $c$s be a problem?

Comment: @Hendrick: Could you please provide a formal proof or some directions (lemma/theorem)? I mainly read "Discrete Mathematics and Its Application", but it does not seem to be "deep" enough about this.

Comment: I think Hendrik Jan is correct and you can use the pumping lemma to prove it.

Comment: @Huynh Formal proof of the first part of the argument. Suppose that $L$ is context-free. Since the intersection of a context-free language with a regular language is context-free, then $L \cap b^*c^*b^*c^* = \{b^mc^mb^mc^m \mid m \geqslant 0 \}$ should be context-free.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hendrik mentioned,
if m is not to be remembered ie it can be different than I think following grammar will work ..
$$
A \rightarrow   a A D | a B D | \lambda
$$

$$
B \rightarrow b B c | b B c P|P
$$
$$
P\rightarrow bPc|bPcB|\lambda
$$
$$
D \rightarrow d
$$

Comment: I think this is not correct though. For example: A->aAD->aD->a, and the number of a's is not the same number of d'.

Comment: thanks @Huynh for pointing this out I will try to correct that....

Comment: This answer could be improved if you added some *ideas* to it. As it stands, it solves the specific question (if that) but does not help the OP in solving similar problems.