# Prove not context free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

How can we prove that:

$$
L = \{ w_1\#w_2 \mid w_1 \in w_2;\; |w_2| > |w_1|;\; w_1 , w_2 \in \{0, 1\}^*\}
$$

is not context-free?

The language defines $w_1$ as a sub-string of $w_2$, and they are separated by a $\#$. This is easy with the CFG pumping-lemma for a slightly different language with $|w_2| \ge |w_1|$ by using the special case of $|w_2| = |w_1|$ (i.e. $w_1 = w_2$).

But here, $w_1$ is a proper sub-string of $w_2$ so I can't do the same. I fail to push the string out since we can always pump, for example the first symbol of $w_2$.

Comment: Some questions can't be shown to be non-context-free by the Pumping lemma; I recommend you check out [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843) for more methods.

Comment: The $|w_2| \ge |w_1|$ is easy, $|w_2| > |w_1|$ is hard. So this site should not have any pumping-lemma applications in the future just because of that *duplicate* question?

Comment: Okay, now I understand the question; thanks for clarifying. It probably *is* still a duplicate (I'd imagine Ogden's lemma might work, but I did not try it out) and you don't really display your attempt (cf [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question)). You do note why the Pumping lemma fails, though, so I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt and reopen.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware of any theorems saying the pumped string should contain all distinct symbols in a sub-string with some sufficient length?

Comment: @perreal There is no such theorem since it's not true. Consider for example the language $a^*$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large enough $p$, consider the word $w = 0^{p+1}1^{p+1}\#0^{p+1}1^{p+2} \in L$. Mark the part $1^{p+1}\#0^{p+1}$. According to Ogden's lemma, we can write $w = uxyzv$ such that $xyz$ contains at least $1$ and at most $p$ marked symbols, and $ux^iyz^iv \in L$ for all $i \geq 0$. The pumped part $xyz$ cannot lie all to the right of $\#$ since then pumping it down would result in a word not in the language (here we crucially use the fact that only the $0^{p+1}$ part to the right of $\#$ is marked). It also cannot lie all to the left of $\#$ since then pumping it up would result in a word not in the language. It follows that the part of $xyz$ to the right of $\#$ is of the form $0^k$, and the part of $xyz$ to the left of $\#$ is of the form $1^\ell$ (otherwise, there would be more than $p$ marked symbols). However, pumping up, the resulting word is not in the language. This contradiction shows that $L$ is not context-free.

Comment: Can we not use the same logic to prove $0^n1^n$ is not CFG by marking 0's? Sorry if this sounds dumb.

Comment: Hopefully not. Try it out to see what goes wrong. Check out the statement of Ogden's lemma first.

Comment: I think what goes wrong with $0^n1^n$ is, we have to show for all possible markings to show non-cfl. I also think since you are just showing a single possible marking in the proof it is not complete. So perhaps this language obeys the lemma's.

Comment: @perreal Ogden's lemma states that there exists $p$ such that for every word in $L$ and every possible marking with at least $p$ marks, there is a way to break the word in a certain way and pump it in a certain way. We get to chose the marks. Otherwise Ogden's lemma doesn't give us anything beyond the usual pumping lemma.