# Using the Chomsky-Schutzenberger theorem to prove a language is not context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, context-free, proof-techniques

The [Chomsky-Schutzenberger representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_representation_theorem) states that a language $L$ is context-free iff there is a homomorphism $h$, a regular language $R$, and a paired alphabet $\Sigma = T \cup \overline{T}$ such that $L = h(D_\Sigma \cap R)$, where $D_\Sigma$ is the [Dyck language over $\Sigma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language). This is a necessary and sufficient condition for a language to be context-free, so in principle it seems like it should be possible to show that a language is *not* context-free by showing that there are no valid choices for $h$, $\Sigma$, and $R$ satisfying the theorem.

[This earlier question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free/) talks about approaches for showing that a language is not context-free, but doesn't mention this approach. Additionally, I can't seem to find any constructive examples of proofs of non-context-freeness along these lines.

Are there any known examples of languages that have been shown not to be context-free by means of the Chomsky-Schutzenberger theorem?

Comment: but note the [general problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Being_in_a_lower_or_higher_level_of_the_Chomsky_hierarchy) of determining whether a language is CFL is undecidable.

Comment: I guess I'm saying a banality here, but in practice the pumping lemma (for CF languages) is infinitely easier to use as a proof technique at least for textbook-level problems.

Comment: Here's a less banal fact: in 2009 Mans Hulden
created a [parsing algorithm based on the C-S thorem](http://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~mhulden/hulden_ltc_2009.pdf).

Answer (score -3):

here is a construction not *exactly* as requested but related/ somewhat similar. the contrapositive of the Chomsky-Schutzenberger theorem can be used to prove a language is not *unambiguously CFL*. it describes the close connection of the construction to generating functions that yields key insight into the problem.

see [ORDINARY GENERATING FUNCTIONS OF CONTEXT-FREE
GRAMMARS](http://scholarworks.gvsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1002&context=mathundergrad) / TANNER SWETT, EDWARD ABOUFADEL, sec 2.6 p 6

Comment: It think you're confusing this representation theorem of C&S with the homonymous [enumeration theorem for unambiguous CFLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_enumeration_theorem). It's the latter that's used in the paper you cited for the purpose you cited.