# Is $\{u u^R u : u \in \Sigma^*\}$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Given a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ with more than one symbol, **is $L = \{u u^R u : u \in \Sigma^*\}$ context-free**? ($u^R$ is the reverse word of $u$)

I tried to show it wasn't context-free by using the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Try applying the pumping lemma on $a^nb^{2n}a^{2n}b^n$.

Comment: By the way, the answer depends on the size of $\Sigma$. When $\Sigma$ is a singleton, the language is regular.

Comment: See our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) for more methods.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks, I edited the statement of the problem to clarify that $|\Sigma| > 1$

Comment: This should not be context free ,to accept this language you need more than one stack.

Answer (score -2):

Based on : [Pumping Lemma for Context-Free Languages for reversal language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/pumping-lemma-for-context-free-languages-for-reversal-language)

By @lukas.coenig

{ww$^R$w| w $\in$ {a,b}*} doesn't seem to be a context-free language over $\Sigma$  of length two.

Assuming this language isn't context free over an alphabet of size 2 to prove it also over size of 3.. and so on by induction might be interesting..(and if true by induction than there is probably a better way to prove it)