# Finding a context free grammar (CFG) for a non-context free language (CFL) a^n b^n c^n

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

It is known that the language $\{a^nb^nc^n|n\geq0\}$ is not context-free (we can prove it using the pumping lemma, as shown here: [Is $a^n b^n c^n$ context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33153/is-an-bn-cn-context-free)). Yet, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930788/context-free-grammar-for-abc-an-bn-cn-n-0) claims it has found a context-free grammar for this language. My question is, is it possible to find a context free grammar for a not context-free language?

Comment: The CFG is not given for $L = \{a^nb^nc^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ in the post you quote, but for $a^*b^*c^*\setminus L$ which is context-free.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Every context-free grammar generates a context-free language.  If you can find a context-free grammar for a language, then the language is context-free.

That assumes the claimed grammar is correct.  People claim all sorts of things on the Internet.  I wouldn't believe it until you have verified or proven it correct.  In this particular case, the answer was incorrect and the grammar doesn't work.  I left a comment explaining, and indeed, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67189460/781723) already responded to that erroneous claim.