# Is this a context free language? I need to make PDA but I don't think it is doable

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I got a question:
Design a pushdown automata that can recognize strings in L= {$ a^n b^{2n} c^{3n} | n ≥ 0 $} .
I tried to think and design it, but I couldn't find it. The best that I can think of is L= {$ a^n b^{m} c^{m+n} | m,n ≥ 0 $} . I only can make sure that c appears as much as a+b appear.
So, I'm wondering, is this language context free? Could we make a PDA for it?
Thank you.

Comment: Even $a^nb^nc^n, n \geq 0$ is not context-free ([proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33153/is-an-bn-cn-context-free)). You can create a proof that $a^nb^{2n}c^{3n}$ is not CF similarly.

Answer (score 0):

For $L= \{a^n b^{2n} c^{3n} | n ≥ 0 \}$ you will be failed to make PDA with one-stack. Because here is two comparisons, one $a$ should be checked  against with $2b$ and $3c,$ but when you complete one $a$   checked  against with $2b$ then stack will be empty, and there will be pending of $c$'s computation. This two comparison intuitively proved that your language is CSL accepted by LBA.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this homomorphism:
$ f(a)=a\ ,f(b)=bb,\ f(c)=ccc $

Context free languages are close to revered homomorphism

What is $ f^{-1}(L)? $

I hope that gives you a hint