# Create CFG and pushdown automaton for {ww}

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, regular-languages, pushdown-automata

I've been trying to make a CFG, a pushdown automaton and a regular expression for the language

$\qquad L(M) = \{ww : w \in \{a, b\}^*, |w| \text{ is even}\}$.

I understand how the reverse of the string work, that is

$\qquad L' = \{ ww^R : w \in \{a, b\}^*\}$,

what i am asking for is to do it this way , i have already solved (L') : http://i921.photobucket.com/albums/ad53/Johann_1990/IMG_20150117_132616.jpg

but is there is a way to solve this one too?
$\qquad L(M) = \{ww : w \in \{a, b\}^*, |w| \text{ is even}\}$.

For example, $abaaba \in L$ with $w = aba$.

Comment: Note that $ww = abaaba$ is a bad example (as in, you don't learn anything from it) here as $w = w^R$.

Comment: @Raphael , i need to train my self for any example.. when i am learning ! i know how to make the reverse of string pushdown or cfg, i was just trying something new! Thank you !

Comment: @D.W.,its not the same question am talking about another thing completely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do so as $L$ is not context-free.

See our [reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843) for how to prove that, i.e.

- [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)
- [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)

Comment: so are you saying that it cannot be proved ? only the reverse of the string  can be proved ?

Comment: @AaoIi That's what I'm saying, yes. At least, your first statement. I don't understand the second.

Comment: I'm saying that this L′={wwR:w∈{a,b}∗}, I've seen that its accomplished in cfg and pushdown automata , so why L={ww:w∈{a,b}∗,|w| is even}.cannot be accomplished ? prove is not what I'm asking for, I'm asking for making the cf grammar for it as S -->aB and drawing the pushdown ?

Comment: I recommend you read some literature covering the basics and then go read the questions I link. (Your terminology is shaky; what is "accomplish"?) The answers are all there, hence I only link. (Hint: "L is not context-free" implies "there is no context-free grammar, pushdown-automaton or regular expression for L".)

Comment: i got it, I'm just trying to understand Formal Language and Automata, Thank you for you help :)