# Pumping Lemma for CFG - How to do it?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I'm literally so confused on how to even start this problem of proving that the given language is not Context Free.

```
L = {a^i b^j c^k d^l | i = k and j = l}
```

I know that we have to find cases where it contradicts the three conditions of the pumping lemma in all cases, but I'm not good in doing so.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It might help if you pumped the string $a^pb^pc^pd^p$, where $p$ is the integer of the pumping lemma. There are still a lot of cases to consider, but many of them can be handled in the same way.

Comment: Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) should get you started, in particular with @RickDecker's hint. Once you have an attempt you can edit this into the question and ask a specific question about where you get stuck.