# Prove that L = { wu; wu in {a,b}* and |w| = |u| } is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Prove that $L = \{wu, wu \in \{a,b\}^* \ \land  |w| = |u| \}$ is not regular.

I'm trying to approach this problem with the pumping lemma.

So I know I have to pick a string *s*, which can be split into *xyz* components in terms of the pumping length, *p*.

But I cannot seem to find an s.

For example using $ s = a^p b^p$ or $s = a^p a b^p b $, since $|xy| \le p  \land |y| > 0$, then *y* must contain some *a*'s. So we can try to pump $x y^i z$ to see the new string is still in L.

The issue is that if y contains an even number of *a*'s it can always be pumped because the resulting string will have even length so *w* can be the first half and *u* be the second half.

Comment: Without some more specifications on $w$ and $u$, this *is* a regular language. It consists of all even-length strings over $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @RickDecker Yes, those were my initial thoughts. I had this question on an exam. So the language wouldn't be any different to { $w, w \in  \{a,b    \}^*  \land |w| $ is even  }

Comment: Yup. Exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rick Decker said $L$ is a regular language. For example:
$$L= \mathscr{L}(\,(aa | ab | ba | bb)^*\,)$$

If your teacher asked you to prove that $L$ is not regular in an exam then he is a big troll. Otherwise remember that the pumping lemma is only usefull to prove that a language is not regular and if you fail to find the contradiction in the lemma then that doesn't prove anything. $L$ can be regular or irregular at that point.

In this answer I covered some common mistakes when students use the pumping lemma: [Common Mistakes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/50618/31129)