# Find non CFL $L$ such that Pref($L$) is CFL

Tags: context-free

While studying I've encountered this question written above.
I am familiar to the closure properties of CFL, and even know that $$L=\{a^{j^2}|j\geqslant 0\}$$ ($a$ to the power of ($j$ to the power of $2$))
is one that answers the question, but I don't know how to prove that.

If anyone could explain it to me, it would be excellent!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think proving that $\text{Pref}(L)$ is CFL is the easiest part (it is even regular): ask yourself what are all prefixes of a word $a^{j^2}$.

Proving that $L$ is not CFL is done [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57389/how-to-prove-an2-n0-is-not-context-free).

You can use the pumping lemma for CFL or, even better, the pumping lemma for regular languages (using the fact that a CFL over a one-letter alphabet is a [regular language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/proving-that-any-cf-language-over-a-1-letter-alphabet-is-regular)).

Comment: So we know that $Pref(L)$ is actually $a^*$ ,which of course, is regular?

Comment: Yes. $\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Great.
Thank you very much, Nathaniel!