# Structure of a Pumping Lemma proof: contradiction or counterexample?

Tags: proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

This site is full of Pumping Lemma questions, and I do admit I've not read them all. I've tried some proofs myself and they seem to work, but I can't find anywhere what is the (general) exact structure of a proof where you show a language is not regular or context-free?

Wikipedia and most proofs start with "Suppose $L$ is a regular language", which would mean it is a proof by contradiction, because it isn't.

But the lemma has the quantifiers $\exists, \forall, \exists, \forall$ in order. And in the proof you assume a given constant given by the first $\exists$, and then you come up with some word (the first $\forall$), format it in some given substring division (the second $\exists$) and again come up with some $k$ (second $\forall$) for which you show it is not in $L$.

This seems to me like a counterexample proof ("this is not context-free/regular because I can come up with a counterexample which fails the pumping lemma"), and not a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Right now, I'm tending to think of it as a proof by contradiction, where you reach a contradiction by an example. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Note our reference questions on [regular](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) and [context-free](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) Pumping lemmata, among other things.

Comment: Indeed, lots of people present it as proof by contradiction, but I tend to think of it as proof by contrapositive. The Pumping Lemma states "Regular implies Pumping" and one uses the implication "not-Pumping so not-Regular". The not-Pumping is by example, but in fact infinitely many examples, as for any length one has to find a counter-example of at least that length. Usually these examples have a strict pattern (like $a^nb^n$) and we treat them as a single string, but in the proof logic we have infinitely many of them.

Comment: @Hendrik Jan Oh of course, there's the contrapositive! Indeed, there is a (general) example involved, so this is one good explanation. Thanks! An other explanation is the the example comes up when processing the $\forall$ in a proof by contradiction. But I like your answer better than the others.

Comment: @HendrikJan Hm. In order to show "not pumping" we need to assume it applies, though; then we get "not regular" directly from the contradiction, as that's our assumption.

Comment: @Raphael I don't think so, I think the contrapositive is a valid way of proving this. The inner part of the proof will probably be the same anyway.

Comment: @PHPirate How do you show "not pumping" without first assuming there is a Pumping length?

Comment: @Raphael. Tricky. You can show that the string $a^nb^n$ cannot be pumped with pumping length $n$ by considering all $uvw$ divisions of that string and show none of them satisfy the conditions. Is that b contradiction? If we want to check that 97 is a prime, we test divisors and show they do not work, still I would not call that proof by contradiction?

Comment: @Raphael I try again. Theorem: Every regular language satisfies Nerode. For a given L one computes its equivalence classes and observes there are infinitely many of them. Then I know that L is not regular. But did I first assume that it was regular before applying Nerode? I guess not. I just observed that L had infinitely many classes. Contrapositive, not contradiction. (But the argumentation is all the same anyway.)

Comment: @HendrikJan The difference is that you explicitly compute the classes. We usually don't show "$\forall p. \lnot$ Pumping". There is no easy way, I guess; for every word there are many Pumping constants it does not violate (at least all numbers larger than its length). So you really have to give one example per candidate for $p$. One can write that in the form of a direct proof -- that much I'll agree to. I'll maintain that Pumping lemma proofs are not typically written in that form, but in the form of a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @HendrikJan An alternative form of Pumping lemma proofs may be a good addition to our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843), in particular for those poor folks who don't believe in (read: understand) proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this is not context-free/regular because I can come up with a counterexample which fails the pumping lemma

You are missing that in order to construct this counterexample you have to *assume* that $L$ is regular. Then you *apply* the Pumping lemma, which yields the Pumping length $p$. Only *then* do you construct your (counter)example string (using $p$!) and show that it contradicts the Pumping lemma. Hence, the assumption must be false.

So while you can say that you derive the contradiction using a counterexample, the outer-most proof is by contradiction.
With the assumption, you wouldn't have $p$!

Note that proofs can be nested, so you don't need to see only one proof technique. For instance, induction proofs often use a proof by contradiction inside the inductive step.

Answer (score 1):

The formulation of the Pumping Lemma, with explicit quantifiers, is as follows:

$$\forall L\in REG, \exists p>0, \forall w\in L,|w|>p\Rightarrow \exists x,y,z\in \Sigma^*, w=xyz\wedge c_1\wedge c_2\wedge c_3$$
where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are the conditions of the lemma.

Thus, a proof that a language is not regular is indeed by contradiction. In order to see the general structure of a proof, it is convenient to this of ourselves as trying to contradict the lemma, while an adversary is trying to prove the lemma holds.

Thus, the general structure is as follows. The lemma claims something for every regular language, so we choose a certain language we want to "attack".

Now, the adversary gets to choose $p$, so we write "for every $p>0$". Next, the lemma says something for every $w\in L$ such that $|w|>0$, so we get to pick $w$, but in order to make it useful, we need to pick $w\in L$ such that $|w|>p$ (otherwise the adversary wins vacuously).

Now, we have $\exists x,y,z$, so the adversary chooses them. We thus write "there exist $x,y,z$ such that $w=xyz$". Next, we want to show that at least one of the conditions $c_1,c_2,c_3$ does not hold. Technically, if $c_1$ or $c_2$ don't hold, then the adversary chose "stupidly", and we're done. Thus, we assume that $c_1$ and $c_2$ do hold, and we show that $c_3$ (the pumping argument) fails, and thus we win.

So overall we get the following proof structure:

Assume by way of contradiction that $L\in REG$, then let $p>0$ be its pumping constant. Consider the word $w=...$(something clever). Let $x,y,z\in \Sigma^*$ such that $w=xyz$, and $|xy|\le p$, and $|y|>0$, we show that there exists $i\ge 0$ such that $xy^iz\notin L$, in contradiction to the pumping lemma.

Thus, $L\notin REG$.

Comment: Thanks for the general explanation, but I'm still not sure why my reasoning that this is a counterexample, maybe even inside a contradiction, is wrong? Or maybe is it essentially the same, since you provide a contradiction by counterexample?

Comment: Perhaps you view the "pumped word" as a counterexample. It can indeed be thought of as a counterexample to the claim that every word has a decomposition according to the lemma. But it's not a "counterexample to the language being regular".

Answer (score 1):

In general, proving things is a creative enterprise. As such, there is no "standard template": you're free to do whatever you want, as long as it's logically valid.

In particular, as long as you understand why a proof works, you shouldn't worry too much about whether it's a proof by contradiction, or a proof by counterexample, or something else. That's a bit like a poet wondering whether a particular phrasing they've used is [a zeugma or a syllepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma). As long as it's effective imagery, who cares except the critics?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out, why and how the logic is valid here.

Comment: @PHPirate The logic of what? You've not quoted any proof so I can't tell what logic you're asking about.