# Showing $L=\{a^ib^jc^k: i,j,k \text{ not all equal}\}$ is a CFL a lemma

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, proof-techniques

In their answer, [Janoma](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/279/54352) proves that $\{a^ib^jc^k:i\neq j,j\neq k,i\neq k\}$ is not context-free using Ogden's lemma, but I haven't learned about Ogden's lemma yet. I wanted to know whether Ogden's lemma can be dispensed with.

This could be interpretted as $\{a^ib^jc^k: i,j,k\text{ are not all equal}\}$ correct?
Can someone show that this is context-free without a lemma?
Like making a CFG or PDA?

This is just for my own reference for learning.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding, the proof shows that $L$ is *not* context-free. You can construct neither a CFG nor a PDA for it.

Comment: Yes. I think it is, it can be written as a union of three CF languages, one which has $i \neq j$, another with $j \neq k$ and a third with $i \neq k$.

Comment: I don't understand. Your post mentions both $i\neq j$, $j\neq k$, $k\neq i$ (i.e., no pair of $i,j,k$ equal) and $i,j,k$ not all equal. Which are you asking about? These are two different languages.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the body of the question.  Please edit one or the other to make them self-consistent.