# Determining whether $ L = \{ 0^n1^{n^2} | n \ge 0 \} $ is a CFL

Tags: automata, pumping-lemma, pushdown-automata

Assuming $L$ is defined as follows:

$$ L = \{ 0^n1^{n^2} | n \ge 0 \} $$

I'm trying to either prove/disprove whether $L$ is CFL or not.

My intuition tells me its not CFL since I cannot express the power $n^2$ by itself using CFL, but I'm having trouble proving so using the pumping lemma. 
Also, I failed to create any such PDA (which my intuition says its impossible).

Comment: Try harder applying the pumping lemma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h\colon \{0,1\} \to \{0\}$ be the homomorphism given by $h(0) = \epsilon$ and $h(1) = 0$. If $L$ were context-free, so would $h(L) = \{ 0^{n^2} : n \geq 0 \}$ be. Since $h(L)$ is a unary language, it would be regular. However, a unary language is regular iff it is eventually periodic, which it isn't. Therefore $L$ cannot have been context-free.

More generally, if $L$ is context-free then:

1. The set of lengths of words in $L$ is eventually periodic.
2. The set of number of occurrences of a symbol in $L$ is eventually periodic.

The most general statement of this kind is [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh's_theorem).