# Push-down Automata Construction

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata

Construct a push-down automata to recognize the language $ A = \{u\#v \in \{0,1,\#\}^{*} | u = v^{\complement} \} $. Here, $v^{\complement}$ is the bit-complement of v.

I don't see how to perform this with a LIFO stack. I would like some hints (not a solution) if possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such PDA because $A$ is not context-free. This can be proved by [pumping](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free).