# Is the language $\{a^n b^n c^i | i \leq n\}$ context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to apply the CFL pumping lemma.
And, I've already tried words $a^pb^p$ and $a^pb^pc^p$.
Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: Try *reversing the language* first.

Comment: Sometimes, the Pumping lemma is not strong enough. See [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) for more approaches. (I guess Ogden's lemma would easily work here.)

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to realize that the pumping lemma also allow deleting the pumped segments: $uv^iwx^iy$ with $i=0$.

Comment: @PMar Context free languages are not closed under complement. I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Classical pumping works. According to the pumping lemma we can find a segmentation $uvwxy$ such that $uv^iwx^iy$ is in the language for all $i$.

Start with your own suggestion $a^pb^pc^p $.

Three easy steps.

- Each of the "pumping segments" $v$, $x$ can only be within the boundaries of one the "letter segments" $a^p$, $b^p$, $c^p$.
- It is not possible to have one of $v$ or $x$ to be in the $a^p$ segment without the other being inside the $b^p$ segment. And the other way around. In that case pump down ($i=0$).
- Final possibility both $v$ and $x$ are in $c^p$. Pump up.