# Generate a Grammar from a language(Non-CFL)

Tags: regular-languages, automata, formal-grammars

I tried to solve this question,

We have this Language, L(g)={AA|A={0+1}*}

The output(Productions) must be similar as these = {(11 11), (0 0), (1101 1101), etc..} The left side equal to right side..
VT={1,0}
The problem I used a lot of methods to solve this, like pumping lemma.

This question isn't easy, I hope someone could help.

a try: If we supposed that S->ASD|BSC|E, A->0, B->1, C->0, D->1
E : Empty
S->BSC->BBSCC->BBADCC let's convert from non-treminal to treminal .. BBADCC->>110100  so this Grammar isn't accepted..

How do I make sure left side = right side>

Make sure This isn't duplicated question.

Comment: You've never told us what question you are trying to solve!

Comment: Note that your language isn't context-free.

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site, so it's important to articulate a specific question that you want answered.  We get asked this kind of question a lot, so we've written some reference material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/755 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755.  I suggest you review that material and try applying those methods.

Comment: The question is generate a grammar from this language.

Comment: What kind of grammar? No context-free grammar generates this language.

Comment: Ok, If this cannot be generated, how to proof that this isn't Context free language?