# Is regular expression syntax regular?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Regular expressions are equivalent to DFA's and describe regular languages, but is the language used to construct regular expressions regular?

My guess is that the original syntax (concat, | and *) is, but the Perl-style syntax is not (backtracking). As the newer syntax recognises non regular languages they must also generate non regular languages. If a DFA could recognise a non regular language then there would be a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "original syntax" and PCRE's syntax is not regular. You need parenthesis to override operator precedence, which puts your syntax language into the territory of context free languages.

Comment: so would a push down automata work i.e are the languages Deterministic context-free?

Comment: @beoliver, that's a separate question, which should be asked in a separate post (see the 'Ask Question' button in the upper-right).  However, before asking, you should first try to figure out the answer on your own.  Write a grammar for the syntax, take a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/755 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755, then try applying those methods to the grammar.  If you're still stuck, then ask a new question, and show your progress so far and what you tried.  You should be able to figure out whether it is context-free on your own based on that material.