# Is Python a context-free language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, programming-languages

From [Wikipedia: Off-side_rule#Implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule#Implementation), there is a statement:

> ...This requires that the lexer hold state, namely the current
>   indentation level, and thus can detect changes in indentation when
>   this changes, and thus the **lexical grammar is not context-free** –
>   INDENT/DEDENT depend on the contextual information of previous
>   indentation level.

I'm a bit confused. Some lexical grammars of Python is not context-free but INDENT/DEDENT themselves can be expressed in CFG. So lastly, Python is a context-free language or not?

Comment: It's most certainly not, depending on how you would define the language. (Since there's no compiler, what constitutes a valid program?) See [this question on cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9196/1546).

Comment: @raphael: the text of the language definition, which includes a grammar? The operation of the builtin `ast` module, which converts a string to an AST or reports failure? Why do you need a compiler per se?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Context-free grammars cannot express the rules of INDENT/DEDENT and so Python (which we use today in practice with INDENTs/DEDENTs)is not pure CF. Parsers (or lexical analyzers or lexers) for these languages use additional techniques to handle those structures. For example keep track of indentation levels, or tokenizer (scanners) may count number whitespaces and store that info in a table for later use. This is similar to something like trying to write a parser for the language $a^nb^{2n}c^n$, where you must keep track of value of $n$.

A simple example of adding additional power to a lexer is removing redundant whitespace symbols (space/tabs/newlines) or removing comments which has no meaning for the parser (parsing a CFL).

**As another example, roughly it can be described as following. Assume a grammar $a^nb^mc^k$ which is clearly CFG.  You use BISON/YACC like tools to generate a parser for this grammar. Then you can introduce an additional rule like number of $a$s must be equal to the number of $c$ which makes the language non CF. So you just add extra logic (manually coding) to your parser to handle that rule by means of, say, annotated trees. Your original language is still context free but extra piece of code you added manually allows it to accept non CF subset of the original language.**

I don't think that such parsers are generated automatically by compiler tools (at least I don't know) and so that ("non context free") part must be coded manually.

Comment: But basically, INDENT/DEDENT are defined as terminal symbols right? Which is one of the members of grammar G here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Formal_definitions . So, how does INDENT/DEDENT violate the definition of CFG.

Comment: "Context-free grammars cannot express the rules of INDENT/DEDENT": It does in Python (ref: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html). You would like to say that regex cannot express INDENT/DEDENT right?

Comment: In fact, it is not INDENT/DEDENT that violates the definition of CFG, but their count. You have to keep track of counts of INDENT if you for example allow nested indents. How can you incorporate that information (#of indents)  into a CFG?

Comment: I am not expert in Python compiler implementation, but I guess the lexer emits  INDENT tokens as input to the parser every time the lexer sees whitespace symbols together with their count, and parser decides whether the Python code has grammar errors or not.

Comment: I updated the post. Please have a look.

Comment: I understood you but there is no `n`, `m` or `k` appeared in level of Python's parser. There is only INDENT/DEDENT which are already assumed to be an "alphabet of the language". Counting is performed in a scanning process, this violates regular language rule but not CFG.

Comment: @fronthem your quote says "lexical grammar", so it's talking about *generating* INDENT/DEDENT from raw bytes, not about using INDENT/DEDENT as brackets.

Comment: Example with n, m, k is just an analogy. In case with Python you are right there is only indents which scanned by lexer. But it also counts it and the number of indents is taken into consideration when the parser decides which statement belongs to which block. Does not that brake the rule?

Comment: `suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT` A suite produces a simple statement, or a new line followed by indentation, followed by dedent. The production rule itself takes care of the count of INDENT/DEDENT. Any nested indentation produced by `stmt` is tracked recursively. e.g. stmt -> compound_stmt->if_stmt->'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite].

Any suite produced by a compound statement tracks it's own INDENT/DEDENT. Hence, the python grammar is CFG.

Answer (score -1):

Python is not a context free language. We can check any language context free or not using [Odgens's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden's_lemma) (In the theory of Formal languages).

Comment: And what would that look like? Our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) lists many methods of showing that a language is not context-free; what's the lesson here?

Comment: why does this answer got negative vote, when it basically saying similar thing (that python is non-CF) as the other answer?

Comment: @kate because Ogden's lemma (not Odgen btw), is notoriously hard to apply to show that a language is not context free. Even for simple examples it's extremely hard to apply. The pumping lemma for rational languages is already hard to apply, but Ogden's lemma is a whole other level

Answer (score -1):

It is not context free. I.e., it is illegal to call a function that isn't defined, and that can't be expressed by a context free grammar. Or just write `print(a)` at your nearest Python interpreter, it will inform you `a` isn't defined.

Comment: Python (or at least CPython) does an initial parsing pass over every file, and `SyntaxError`s raised at that time can't be caught by the code being parsed (since it never runs). Your examples raise `NameError` or `UnboundLocalError` at run time, which can be caught and handled just like `FileNotFoundError`, so I don't think it's reasonable to treat them as grammatical errors.

Comment: It's not illegal to call an undefined function.  It's illegal to try to resolve an undefined name to a value whether it's used in a call or not: `undefined()` is equivalent to `x = undefined; x()`.  That illegality, the *NameError*, is only resolved after parsing, not via grammatical rules.  `def calls_undefined(): undefined()` parses just fine.

Answer (score -4):

No, Python is not a context-free language. It is a programming language that follows a syntax defined by a context-sensitive grammar. Context-free languages are a subset of formal languages that can be described by context-free grammars, where the structure of the language is determined solely by the arrangement of its symbols, independent of any context or surrounding symbols. However, Python's syntax includes constructs like indentation and significant whitespace, which make it context-sensitive. These features affect the meaning and behavior of the code, and they depend on the context in which they are used.

Comment: The tutorial link is not relevant to this answer or to the question.