# Proving this language is not context free using the pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I am trying to prove why the below language is not context free. Note: this should be carried out by applying the pumping lemma for context free languages.

[image]

To prove something with the pumping lemma, we firstly need to choose an arbitrary m > 0. After that we need to formulate the string (alpha below) we are going to reach a contradiction with. But how do I formulate that string? Rational thinking lead me to believe it's the following:

[image]

What do I do next?
I have no idea about the length of $w$, and therefore the above approach seems kind of useless.

Is the solution to constrain $w$ to be of length at most $m$?
But again, I wouldn't know what to do from there.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: You may want to check out [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free). Duplicate?

Comment: Note that you can include LaTeX directly into your posts by using `$...$` and `$$...$$`. There's no need to link to third-party sites that render LaTeX as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the notation of the language superscript $R$ is *not* a number; you cannot choose it to be a length $m$.

Instead $R$ usually denotes the operation of "mirror image" which inverts a string: $(abbaa)^R = aabba$.

Now start rereading your notes on the Pumping Lemma.