# A push down automaton that recognize exponential strings

Tags: finite-automata, pushdown-automata

How can I describe a Push Down Automaton that recognize the language $P=\{a^{2^n} | n \geq 0 \}$?

**My approach**

I know that the language can be described by a Turing Machine, but how i can the stack recognize that language?

Comment: This is impossible. You can show it is **not** context-free by applying the Pumping Lemma.

Comment: Existence of a TM accepting a language $L$ does not guarantee existence of a PDA accepting this language. Please look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free).