# How to show that a language is strictly context sensitive

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

During a class, we was asked how to prove that a language L is **strictly** context-sensitive. In particular, we have to prove that

$L =  \{a^nb^nc^n \mid n > 0\}$

Could you help me to find the answer providing a detailed solution?

**My approach:**

I know that a language is strictly of type $n$ if there isn't a type-$j$-grammar ($j > n$) that can generate it.

So i wonder if i can apply the Pumping Lemma for Context Free Languages to prove that.

Comment: To prove a language is strictly RE, you'd have to prove it's RE and not context-sensitive. But that language *is* context-sensitive (in fact it's the very first example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples)).

Comment: "Pumping Lemma for Context Free Languages" -- that can be used to show that the language is not context-free -- see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/276/98) -- but not that it's not context-sensitive.

Comment: I made a mistake. I need to prove that $L$ is *strictly* context-sensitive. If the language is not context-free, then maybe is context-sensitive. But how to prove the "strictness" ? Showing a context-sensitive grammar for it?

Comment: The strictness you prove by showing that the language is not context-free, for example via the Pumping Lemma (I guess in your nomenclature CF is type 2 and CS type 1, so you need to prove that it is not type 2). The other part of the proof is showing that L is context-sensitive/type 1, for example by describing an LBA for it.