# Is the language in the description context free?

Tags: formal-languages

I am stuck on a question. Lets say there is a string that can be created from three alphabets a,b,c the condition is number of a<= number of b<= number of c. I can solve if there are a and b (two alphabets) but I am not able to solve for 3. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your language is not context free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: I have a hard time to find even a question here. People have been guessing you're trying to ask for a PDA for the given language. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that context-free languages are not closed under intersection.

The example you give illustrates this. Thus, $\{ w\in\{a,b,c\}^* \mid |w|_a \le |w|_b\}$ is context-free, and similarly, so is $\{ w\in\{a,b,c\}^* \mid |w|_b \le |w|_c\}$. The intersection of these two languages $\{ w\in\{a,b,c\}^* \mid |w|_a \le |w|_b \le |w|_c\}$ is not context-free.

Comment: So that is the reason I was not able to come up with a PDA for this. I had been trying for so long every time something or the other will not work. Thanks a lot for clarifying this.