# Is a^mb^n where m=n^2 a CFL?

Tags: automata, context-free

Is $a^mb^n$ where $m=n^2$ a CFL?

---

I have a doubt regrading this problem. Say if we pop $n$ number of $a's$ from the stack for each $b$ then it is a CFL (to be exact DCFL) right?

On the other hand I have this doubt, do we know the number of $b's$ we are provided with, if not how can we pop $n$ number of $a's$ for each $b$? So this case doesn't make it a CFL right?

Which of these 2 cases are applicable? Are we always aware of the number of $b's$ we have? Then shouldn't it be a *regular language*?

Comment: Did you try the pumping lemma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a context-free language, as an immediate consequence of [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem).

In terms of pushdown automata, there is no way for a PDA to keep track of the number of $b$'s in the string in a way it can access *repeatedly* while reading (or popping) the $a$ part of the string. This is an essential feature of context-free languages; it is the same reason why languages such as $\{a^n b^n c^n d^n | n > 0\}$ are not context-free.

For more examples, check out [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/8311) on proving languages are not context-free.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative argument. Let $h$ be the homomorphism given by $h(a) = \epsilon$, $h(b) = b$. Then
$$ h(L) = \{ b^{n^2} : n \geq 0 \}. $$
If $L$ were context-free, then $h(L)$ would be unary context-free, and so regular. But $h(L)$ is not eventually periodic.

You can also show that $h(L)$ is not context-free using the pumping lemma. The pumping lemma gives us a constant $p$ such that $b^{p^2}$ can be partitioned into $uxyzw$, where $|xyz| \leq p$, $|xz| \neq 0$, and $ux^iyz^iw \in h(L)$ for all $i \geq 0$. Let $|xz| = q$. Then $ux^2yz^2w = b^{p^2+q}$, but $p^2 < p^2+q \leq p^2 + p < p^2+2p+1 = (p+1)^2$, and so $b^{p^2+q} \notin h(L)$.

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)