# Proof that $\{a^ib^jc^k\mid i,j,k\in\mathbb{N}, i<k<j\}$ is not context-free using the Pumping Lemma

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

$$
L=\{a^ib^jc^k \;| \;i, j, k \in \mathbb{N} \; \text{and} \; i <k<j\}
$$

I need to show that this language is not context-free with the help of the Pumping Lemma.
My first intuition is, that there exist 5 different cases, i.e. the middle part, let's call it vwx, consists of

1. only $a$'s
2. only $b$'s
3. only $c$'s
4. $a$'s and $b$'s
5. $b$'s and $c$'s

and I need to find a pumping constant, which excludes the new word from the above defined language. However, I am having a hard time how show that formally and precisely. Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! Take a look at this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free reference question

Answer (score 1):

Your case analysis seems right and can be used to prove non-contextfreeness.

Not you don't have to find a pumping constant. To the contrary, you have to show no such constant can exist. So, the general argument is usually like "if I assume $N$ is the pumping constant, I can use this word $x\in L$, longer than $N$, and whatever I try, we cannot pump it and stay in $L$."

Usually one choses a string that is "just" inside the language, in this case $a^Nb^{N+1}c^{N+2}$. Now check your cases. What if we pump $a$'s and or $b$'s, but no $c$'s etcetera.

One final hint, which seems necessary here. One cannot only "pump up", but also "pump down".