# Check if a language is context free

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Check whether the following language is context-free. If yes, a suitable grammar should be given; if no, the pumping lemma should be used as a tool.

$$L=\{a^ib^jc^k \mid i, j, k \in N \text{ and } i <k<j\} $$

Can I choose (since N includes 0)

$$ L=\{b^jc^k \mid j,k >= 1 \text{ and } j > k\} $$

and provide a grammar for that language, and thus say L is indeed context-free?
If L is not context-free, how could I prove it using the Pumping Lemma?

Comment: Does [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140991/proof-that-aibjck-mid-i-j-k-in-mathbbn-ikj-is-not-context-free-usi) answer your question?

Comment: Also, if $L\subset L'$ and $L$ is context-free, that does not mean that $L'$ is context-free, but that is the reasoning you are trying to do.